# Need Help Translating This Oracle SQL Into T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Need help to convert the following Oracle SQL query into an T-SQL query

```
SELECT rh.user_name, rh.report_name, rh.report_run_date
FROM report_history rh,
  (SELECT max(report_run_date) as maxdate, report_name
   FROM report_history
   GROUP BY report_name) maxresults
WHERE rh.report_name = maxresults.report_name
AND rh.report_run_date= maxresults.maxdate;
```

Comment: What have you tried? What error do you get when you run this query inside MSSQL?

Comment: This ought to run as it is - it looks like there are no Oracle-specific features being used.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be entitled "Convert from old-school to new-school SQL"?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  rh.user_name, 
  rh.report_name, 
  rh.report_run_date

FROM 
  report_history rh

  INNER JOIN 
  (
     SELECT 
       max(report_run_date) as maxdate, 
       report_name
     FROM 
       report_history
     GROUP BY 
       report_name

  ) maxresults
  ON rh.report_name = maxresults.report_name
  AND rh.report_run_date= maxresults.maxdate;
```